# Update attendees response status - Google Calendar API (PHP)

Tags: php, google-calendar-api

I've made a little application that uses Google Calendar API and Oauth2.
Now I would like to allow user to answer at an event. This is my code:

PHP

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $eventSubmit = $service->events->get('primary', $_POST['eventID']);
    $attendeesSubmit=$eventSubmit->getAttendees();

    foreach ($attendees as $attendee) {
        $mailSubmit = $attendee->getEmail();

        if ($mailSubmit==$emailUser){

            if ($_POST['status']=='accepte'){
               $attendee->setResponseStatus('accepted');
               $service->events->update('primary', $_POST['eventID'], $eventSubmit);

            }
            if ($_POST['status']=='decline'){
                $attendee->setResponseStatus('decline');
            }

        }

}
```

HTML

```
    <form method="post" action="index.php">
    <input type="radio" name="status" id="accepte" value="accepte">Confirmer</input>
    <input type="radio" name="status" id="decline" value="decline">Décliner</input>
    <input type="hidden" name="eventID" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($event['id']); ?>">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="OK"></br></br>
```

But It doesn't work, user's reponse status doesn't change when I'm submit the form. What's the problem?

Comment: Please explain your issue clearly? Are you not getting notifications when the invitees accept the invitation? is this is the case, in your calendar settings change remindOnRespondedEventsOnly to true. Check this link https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/settings

Comment: No, I created a little form where, for each event where he's invited, user can choice an answer: accepte or decline. But, when I submit the form, the user's answer doesn't change in this event, and I don't understand why

Answer (score 1):

Event creators/owners can't modify the response of attendees. Only attendees can modify their status. Either attendees will need to respond from the Google Calendar UI themselves or you'll need to authenticate as the attendee user and change their response status.

Comment: Yes, I know that, so when I test my application, I log with my own Google Account and I try to respond to my own event (where someone else invited me) and my appli doesn't work. Maybe it's not possible to modify status with Google Calendar API and only with the official calendar?