# Creator does not receive notification email about attendee response status in google calendar api

Tags: google-calendar-api

I am using service account to authenticate google calendar.
 There is one admin (organizer) for my application and multiple users (creators) who creates event on behalf of admin and invitation email goes to attendees as well as organizer about event creation. But the issue is, there is intimation to creator about the response status of the attendee.

organizer(abc@gmail.com) receives the response status email of (acceptance or declined) of an attendee but creator(xyz@gmail.com) doesn't not receive my email.

```
/*adding organizer data */
Event.OrganizerData org = new Event.OrganizerData();
org.Email = gm.Organizer; //abc@gmail.com
eventEntry.Organizer = org;
    /*adding creator data */
Event.CreatorData creator = new Event.CreatorData();
creator.Email = gm.CreatedBy; //xyz@gmail.com
eventEntry.Creator = creator;
/*inserting an event to service account calendar*/
  var request = er.Insert(eventEntry, calID);
                    request.SendNotifications = true;
                    var re = request.Execute();
```

how do I achieve this requirement. I did lot of researching on internet but did not find any answer.

Comment: Make sure that in your calendar settings, [`remindOnRespondedEventsOnly`](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/settings) is set to true. You may check this related [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29301309/update-attendees-response-status-google-calendar-api-php). From this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/update), you can use the `sendNotifications` parameter to send notifications about the event update (e.g. attendee's responses, title changes, etc.). The default is False.

Comment: sorry, i guess you have not understood my question properly. i dont want to modifying response status that is done by attendee. what i want is organizer (abc@gmail.com) getting email notification of attendee response status but the creator (xyz@gmail.com) is not getting the  email notification of attendee response status.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's late though.

SendNotifications is deprecated now. Use SendUpdates method. See the official doc [here](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert?hl=en_US)